# Is there a way to see how much leverage a mutual fund or ETF is using to generate a return

Tags: mutual-funds, options, etf, derivatives, leverage

I am taking over some of my IRA and 401K money and I want to move towards a more value based approach with an emphasis on dividends. One thing I have learned on this quest is that most options have the ability to use leverage and derivatives to generate return. I wanna make sure that my investments are not sitting with PMs who are too reliant on gambles to kick out a dividend so I do not get soaked.

My question to the community is how can I check if a fund/ETF is highly leverage at any given point in time? I am leaning more towards ETFs since I like being able to bail out at any point of the day. Ideally I want high dividend yield ETFs but if a firm is rolling the dice with options and other exotic stuff I would like to know. The charter says what is allowed but it doesn't say what is currently being done. Is there any way see through this veil?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Index funds generally don't leverage, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak about mutual funds, but ETFs are generally either leveraged or they're not.  When they are leveraged, they advertise their target leverage ratio.  If you want to know exactly minute-to-minute to the extent that leverage is actually a bit variable, I think that's not available.  You can get the leverage on ETFs several ways:

- Usually (if not always) the leveraged ETFs will have some clue in their name like "UltraShort" or "2x" that at least gives a clue if not the leverage amount.  Then when you read their prospectus, you should be able to get the amount.
- If you search online, you can find complete lists of all leveraged ETFs currently available.
- Any decent online broker should provide this in their summary of the ETF under their "research tools."